# Proving a set is a subspace of a given vector space question

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm familiar with proving subspaces but am unsure over how to approach this question. I don't understand what the notation is implying about $S$ so any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Decide if set $S$ is a subspace of the given vector space $V$.

$V=\mathbb{R}^2 \; and\;S=\{w=(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |\; x\ge0\}.$

Comment: Let apply the definition properties for a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let consider

- $w_1=(1,0)\in S$
- $w_2=(2,0)\in S$

and then consider the combination

- $1\cdot w_1+(-1)\cdot w_2$

Comment: Gotcha, I feel silly now

Comment: @RJM You are welcome! Never mind, now you have solved your doubts. And what about $$V=\mathbb{R}^2 \; and\;S=\{w=(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |\; |y|\le |x|\}$$

Comment: Consider

$w_1=(1,1) \; and \; w_2=(0,-1), \; \; w_1,w_2 \in S$

Consider $w_1+w_2$

Comment: note that $w_2$ is not in $S$, we can consider $w_1=(1,1)$ and $w_2=(-1,1)$

Comment: Yep, misread - though it was $|y|\ge |x|$

Comment: @RJM ah ok then you was right!